# Have CSS issue on Safari browser. All buttons and some other elements Css not applied on safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, elementor

I have a page that is built with elementor and write some custom CSS on different elements. all is working fine on all other browsers and mobile devices but on the Safari browser on `iPhone devices` or `Mac Devices` buttons styling is disturbed.

**Chrome View**

[image]

**Safari View**

[image]

CSS code of those two buttons that works in every browser except Safari

```css
.slide-btn-1{
    background: #FBDB1F;
    padding: 12px 40px 12px 40px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border:1px solid #FBDB1F;
}
.slide-btn-1:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.slide-btn-2{
    border:1px solid #FBDB1F;
    padding: 12px 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.slide-btn-2:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

**Page Link:** https://s42602.p1227.sites.pressdns.com/home-version-2/

Comment: Please can you provide the CSS code in the question itself? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: .slide-btn-1{
    background: #FBDB1F;
    padding: 12px 40px 12px 40px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border:1px solid #FBDB1F;
}
.slide-btn-1:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.slide-btn-2{
    border:1px solid #FBDB1F;
    padding: 12px 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.slide-btn-2:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}

Comment: i Paste css code in my question also.  please review it

Comment: When you use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied to that anchor element what do you see? Is there some difference in Safari?